# Converting x/y coordinates to spherical

Tags: ruby, math

Given a flat (equarectangilar panoramic) image of for instance 6000px x 3000px (spreading 360 degrees wide and 180 degree high). How would I translate for instance x = -10, y=-10 to spherical coordinates (pan/tilt or vertical/horizontal offset) where the center of the image would mean a horizontal/vertical offset of 0?

Is it possible to calculate this, or do you need other variables like the radius, distance or z coordinate?

**Edit:
What I have so far:**

```
def self.translate_xy_to_spherical(x, y)
  h = (x / (6000 / 360)) - 180
  v = ((y / (3000 / 180)) - 90) / - 1
  [h, v]
end

def self.translate_spherical_to_xy(h, v)
  x = ((h + 180) * (6000  / 360))
  y = ((v * -1) + 90) * (3000/ 180)

  [x, y]
end
```

If I put in 0,0 in the first method, I get -180,90 which is correct. But if I set 3000,0 I'd expect 0,90 but I get 7,90. Same goes with the other formula (xy to spherical). When I input 0,0 I'd expect 3000,1500 but I get  2880x1440px. There is a small offset, probally because I calculate in a straight line.

**Update: The Answer**

I've updated the answer from below to take in account that degrees could be bigger than 360 degrees. I use the modulo to fix this:

```
IMAGE_WIDTH = 6000
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 3000
def self.translate_xy_to_spherical(x, y)
  h = (x / (IMAGE_WIDTH / 360.0)) - 180
  v = ((y / (IMAGE_HEIGHT / 180.0)) - 90) / -1
  [h, v]
end

def self.translate_spherical_to_xy(h, v)
  x = (((h % 360) + 180) * (IMAGE_WIDTH  / 360.0))
  y = (((v % 180) * -1) + 90) * (IMAGE_HEIGHT/ 180.0)

  [x, y]
end
```

Comment: Do you want to map a flat image to sphere ?

Comment: Yes, an equarectangilar flat image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection

Comment: Why can't you use the formulas from wikipedia ?

Comment: I've edited my question with what I have so far. I've seen dozens of formulas on wikipedia, but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for. Spherical, cartessian, polar, cylindrical. Also most talk about distances and a z coordinate. For instance: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node42.html I can't see how to apply this

Comment: Do you know what you want to translate your x/y coordinates to/from? If you want spherical, that's a radius and two angles. If you want latitude/longitude, that's two angular values that don't have a radial dimension. I don't think you want cylindrical (just a hunch). What are you wanting to use this for?

Comment: I want to place image hotspots on a flat image. Once the user is done, I convert the flat image to an spherical using krpano. But I need to translate the x/y to lat/lon (I know krpano has methods for this, but I want to do this serverside).

I've looked at http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/conversion-between-spherical-and-cartesian-coordinates-systems/

And from what I see, I have the y, x and r (half image width). z would be sqrt(r2 - x2 - y2) right? But what would the lat and lon be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equations are mathematically correct, but when dividing integers in Ruby (and in most languages), you will lose the remainder.  For example 6000/360 = 16.666... in real life, but in Ruby you'll get 16.  All these rounding errors will lead to errors in your final result.  A trick to avoid this avoid this is to make some of the numbers in your arithmetic are Floats instead of just Fixnums.  Try:

```
def self.translate_xy_to_spherical(x, y)
  h = (x / (6000 / 360.0)) - 180
  v = ((y / (3000 / 180.0)) - 90) / - 1
  [h, v]
end

def self.translate_spherical_to_xy(h, v)
  x = ((h + 180) * (6000  / 360.0))
  y = ((v * -1) + 90) * (3000/ 180.0)

  [x, y]
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I'm still confused about the wiki articles I found across the internet, where they use metrics and all kinds of angle calculation and take even the radius of the earth in account. Is this the correct way> Or do I still calculate in a straight line?

Comment: The first Wikipedia article you link to in your comments translates between latitude-longitude on the *real Earth* to x-y coordinates on a flat equirectangular projection of the Earth's surface onto a 2-dimensional flat *map*.  The link to the geom.uiuc.edu page gives a translation between latitude-longitude-"distance-from-core-of-the-Earth" for the *real Earth in real space* to Cartesian x-y-z coordinates in *real space*, with origin located at the Earth's core with the x-axis going through the Prime Meridian at the Equator, and the z-axis going through the Earth's poles...

Comment: ... So these two translations are entirely different.  The first set is *two-dimensional*, and goes between the *surface* of the Earth and Cartesian co-ordinates on a *map*, whereas the second is *three-dimensional*, and goes between two different ways to represent points in 3-d space, where both coordinates systems happen to be geocentric.